# Why does this evaluate to {}?

Tags: equation-solving

I'm stuck with what seems to be an extremely simple issue, still, I just can't seem to find the solution or even the cause of the problem.

So my issue is that I have the following surfaces:

```
f[x_,y_]:=-1 + 1/(1.8 (0.02 + x) + 1.2 (0.02 + y));
g[x_,y_]:=-1 + 1/(0.15 + x + 1.2 (0.15 + y));
```

which intersect for sure, I checked via Plot3D, but

```
Solve[f[x,y]==g[x,y],y]
```

returns {}. This baffles me, what is happening?

Tried with exact coefficients, tried restarting the kernel, no change.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the inexact numbers with exact ones (e.g. replace `1.8` with `9/5`)?

Comment: When I try to solve it generally, Mathematica produces the warning "Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result." so that doesn't seem to be a problem (or am I missing something? :/ )

Comment: But just to make sure, I tried it with exact coeffs now, to no avail.

Comment: Most likely you want to find the simpltaneous zero set, that is, `Solve[{f[x,y]==0,g[x,y]==0},{x,y}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're asking for a general solution for y only whereas your particular set of equations has a solution only for one specific value of x.

You should have called `Solve` as:

```
Solve[f[x, y] == g[x, y], {x, y}]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>
>
> During evaluation of Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
> ```

```
(* {{x -> 0.3375}} *)
```

or better, with exact coefficients:

```
f[x_, y_] := -1 + 1/(18/10 (2/100 + x) + 12/10 (2/100 + y));
g[x_, y_] := -1 + 1/(15/100 + x + 12/10 (15/100 + y));


Solve[f[x, y] == g[x, y], {x, y}]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
> ```

```
(* {{x -> 27/80}} *)
```

In this case `Reduce` or `SolveAways` would have been better approaches:

```
Reduce[f[x, y] == g[x, y], y]
(* x == 27/80 && 89 + 160 y != 0 *)

SolveAlways[f[x, y] == g[x, y], y]
(* {{x -> 27/80}} *)
```

Comment: But shouldn't this solution also contain a value for y? I'm confused.

Comment: No, for the given value of x *all* y's are a solution. Check `f[27/80, y] - g[27/80, y] // FullSimplify` for the system with exact coefficients.

Comment: Ohh, thanks a lot!